# Grafana - Create Table from Counter Data

Tags: grafana, graphite, codahale-metrics

I have some metrics in Graphite, in the form of a 'count' that has the continuous number of times something happens. I have this brought into Grafana as a 'Time series aggregations' table. This works, however it shows the total count instead of working out the difference between the count at the start and end of the selected time range.

Is there a way, or a function that can be applied, to force Grafana to work out the difference, and show the count of occurrences within the time range?

Answer (score 0):

In the "Metrics"-Tab, add the "perSecond" or "derivative" function. You'll find those in the "Transform"-Menu when clicking the "+" in the "Funtions"-Row of the series.

"perSecond" will calculate the change per Second based on the given values.

"derivative" will calculate the difference between any two given values, ignoring the any time-delta.

You can find all available functions of Graphite here: https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#module-graphite.render.functions